# Ruby on Rails pass button value to next page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I am trying to design a webpage that contains both a radio button field and a list of links.  When one of the links is clicked, I would like to pass the associated value of the button to a controller.  So far I have the following code:

In my views page:

```
<div id="radio_buttons">
    <%= radio_button_tag 'radioGroup', "1" %> 1 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <%= radio_button_tag 'radioGroup', "2" %> 2 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <%= radio_button_tag 'radioGroup', "4" %> 4 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>

...
<div class = "text">
    <%= link_to "mylink", search_path(:radioGroup => @radioGroup)%>
</div>
```

In my Controller:

```
@radioGroup = params[:radioGroup]
```

When I add the line 'puts @radioGroup' to my controller, it prints nothing.  I have been able to pass different values to a new web page upon a link click (i.e those contained in a text field) but for some reason I can't figure out how to do the same thing with buttons. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit multiple values to another page you should use an HTML form for it. Check this page for more related info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The part that is confusing me is that I have been able to pass multiple values to another page, just not the ones from the button.  I accomplish this by doing the following:<%= link_to c, search_path(:var1 =>c,:var2 =>@var2,:var3 => @var3) %>.  However I cant get this to work with the buttons

Comment: If you want to pass a value from a radio button (the selected button in a group) as an HTTP GET parameter with your url, you're probably best of reading the value of the radio button with Javascript at the time you're clicking the link. You can prevent default behaviour of clicks on elements with Javascript, then build up the URL you want to go to (including the value of the radio button as parameter) and then go to that page.